# how to calculate css perspective to work across screen sizes?

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms

I cant get the css perspective property to behave the same across different screen sizes, as I cant understand to what to base the value given to it?

For example if I have some flipping effect on mobile and I give perspective:1000px and its looking good
but when i give the same value on desktop than the effect look different a bit and I just "guessing" the right value depending on screen size.

here is [simple jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8bvde494/)

```
<div class=container>
<div class='e'>

</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
  perspective:1000px;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
.e {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transform-origin: 100%;
}
.e:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(0);
}
```

is there any formula to get the right perspective value to look the same in all screen sizes?(it does not accept percentage only pixels)

Comment: Have you tried using vw, vh, vmin or vmax units for perspective?

Comment: It looks the same to me. Could you post an image showing what is the difference?

Comment: As @web-tiki says, in your case perspective: 1000vw; should give what you are asking for

Comment: @vals Thanks you are right totally missed it

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029605/what-is-the-math-behind-webkit-perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029605/what-is-the-math-behind-webkit-perspective)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) is also an option.

In a project, I wanted to tweak the perspective. After identifying what looked good on the smallest mobile resolution and what looked good on the largest mobile resolution, I used `calc` to create a simple scale that grows with the viewport:

```
perspective: calc( 720px + ( 100vw - 320px ) * 7 );
```

Comment: What does 320 and 720 mean? I guess 320px is for the largest device screen, since it would look very prominent, and 720px is for smallest screen?

Comment: So, `calc(700vw - 1520px)`?

Answer (score 4):

With `CSS Container Queries` finally being [supported in all relevant browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries), the CSS `perspective` property value can be made relative to its parent element (without using the unsupported `%`).

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-outer {
  container-type: size;

  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
  perspective: 80cqw; /* relative to parent element width */

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  transform: rotateX(20deg);

  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-outer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.container{
  perspective:100vw;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
set perspective to 100vw to always have perspective = to your screens width.
```

Credit to @vals in the comments above